# How to get real Z-buffer value from Blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, depth-of-field

This is in follow up to my previous post. I see that i can render the zbuffer into an image from the answer to my [previous pos](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33293/z-buffer-output-from-blender-as-file)t. But can I get the real Z values some how using blender? 
I found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652253/getting-the-true-z-value-from-the-depth-buffer) that talks about it in OpenGL but I am not sure how to access the values in blender. If someone has done this before, please help me out.

Thanks in advance!
Karthik

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hey thanks! The reason I am using the blender is to get render the zbuffer out into a file that I can use for non-visualization purpose. So basically I need the depth values (Float and unnormalized). I am writing them out to .hdr file and getting it now. But I would like to know if I can use python scripting to get to the object that holds these values when I render it out. Because I again have to read the .hdr files externally into a text file to get hold of these values for my project.

Comment: I currently have the same problem. This solution might help you: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35770/depth-map-with-distance-along-the-camera-z-axis But it requires to change all the materials in your scene. Did you find a better solution in the meantime?