# How to have video output different resolution than render layer?

Tags: compositing-nodes

In my compositing Nodetree, I need to create an output which have the input image (1920x**1080** - *Render Layers*) twice (up and below - below part is simplified here).
Thus the output resolution will be 1920x**2160**.

I can use a *File Output* node to generate 1920x2160 frames (and use ffmpeg); but I want to output as *FFmpeg video* directly; however if I change the *Output properties* from 1920x**1080** to 1920x**2160** it affects my camera fov and render useless parts. I also tried to play with the *Output Properties* *Aspect X = 2* and node Scale to cancel it (but it has some strange issue with the depth).

Is that a way to differenciate the *Render Layers* resolution with the *Composite Resolution* ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### One Scene

... a bit of workaround.

To prevent *FOV* change - set *Camera > Sensor Fit >* **Horizontal** ...
for more details [see here.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/220035/2214)

[image]

To prevent rendering of unwanted parts, set **Render Region** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

[image]

Thanks to [Markus von Broady](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/60486/markus-von-broady) for answer extension ...
To set *Region* precisely - Switch *Outliner* > **Data API**, search for *Region* and adjust Min/Max manually ...

[image]

You can also set those values with Python:

```py
C.scene.render.border_min_y = 0.25
C.scene.render.border_max_y = 0.75
```

Composite in a similar way ... Render directly as movie file.

[image]

Comment: @markusvonbroady Thanks for the answer extension ... Great to know :)

Comment: When I search for `Region`, everything disappears, my search is not recursive and only searches through visible elements, is it a bug or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Ha ... same for me. It worked for me because I had hierarchy already expanded. When structure is collapsed it doesn't work for me too. So it probably could be call a bug (from devs point of view probably seen as missing feature). Search works recursively for View Layer, but doesn't for Data API ... so you are right. Also "Expand All" with Shift click is not working here.

Answer (score 1):

### Two Scenes

First scene is set to render 1920x**1080**
Second scene is set to composite 1920x**2160**

[image]

At single blend file you can create several Scenes, so ...
The first scene (lets name it **Scene_1080**) set by default 1920x1080 use to render your model.
For compositing purpose create a *New Scene* (lets name it **Scene_2160**)

- change *Resolution* to 1920x2160
- and for *Render Layer* node switch scene input to *Scene_1080*

*Scale* node is just to generate scene resolution. You can use any other option ... like render empty scene or place image of this dimension and *Mix* it, but *Scale* node seems to be straight forward option.

*Translate* and *Mix* as ussual ... *Render* animation.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks your answers!
I cannot me it works, it's look like I have a bug with the input resolution (probably cropping the input image could dirty fix it). Here is a video link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cyf3tOI3J-k (Blender 3.3.1)

Comment: In the meantime, using instead of your `scale` node `crop` node with cropimagesize=0 relative=1 left=0 right=1 up=0.25 down=0.75 to force crop the input image to 1920x1080 and `Add` instead of `Mix` works

Comment: @RemyMellet I shared my blend (3.4) if you can test the issue ... if my file will work for you you can try to share your blend to let me see ... (if you have issue with my file too it sounds like app issue).

Comment: Now I see the issue :) I didn't hit F12 ... I used icon on "Render Layer" node. Hm ...  I created a task on bug-tracker so we will see what devs think about it https://developer.blender.org/T101993