# Looking for realistic camera and lens model

Tags: rendering, camera

I would like to render a model using simulated specific camera and lens. In particular I would like to use the setup:
Camera Model Name: Canon EOS 6D Mark II
Lens ID: Canon EF 24-105mm f/3.5-5.6 IS STM
Focal Length: 45 mm
Aperture Value:29
Sensor Width: 6384
Sensor Height: 4224

What precautions do I have to take into account in addition to correctly setting the sensor width, height, and focal length on Blender?

Comment: Does this solve your needs? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/220035/2214 Real Camera addon https://3d-wolf.com/products/camera/

Comment: What units are the sensor width and height you are giving there? The EOS 6D is a full-frame DSLR which means the sensor is 36 × 24 mm in size (or actually more like 35.8 × 23.9 mm).

Comment: @vklidu thanks for the suggestion, the add on seems to work for me.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I confirm EOS 6D has a 36 x 24 mm sensor. I misrepresented the data (copied from EXIF metadata).