# How to shoot Rays from all 4 corners of Camera

Tags: rendering, camera, collision

My task is to detect how better a 3d model fits the camera view. The model is always located at he center, while the camera can be placed anywhere.
The model should not be outside the view of camera. For that, I plan to create a Bounding Box across the model, and then shoot rays from Camera's 4 corner points. Wherever the rays collide with the Box, I will note the coordinates and thus, deduce the scaling factor by which the model needs to be scaled down.
I am successful in creating a Bounding Box. Can someone tell me how to shoot rays and find coordinates?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95989/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-dimensions-of-the-camera

Comment: As linked to prior question, it finds the 2D bounding box relative to camera of object of interest https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214572/constrain-a-camera-to-an-object-while-also-aligning-it-perfectly-to-the-center-o/214597#214597  and shifts the camera to center object, scale instead.