# How to do a ray_cast from camera origin(position) to object in scene in such a way that ray would pas through a given pixel coordinate in camera view?

Tags: python, objects, 3d-view

As question states, I want to "extract" global coordinates of 3D point that generated information in a specific pixel in camera view(rendered image).

1. I have a pixel coordinate in a rendered image as (X,Y)<=> (**point P1**)
2. I have (**point O**) as origin of ray

How can I get (X,Y,Z) in global coordinates of (**point P2**) from this setup?

[image]

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/91019/15543) in that it shoots a resolution_x by resolution_y grid of rays from camera onto object of focus, before reflecting onto mirror object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You obtain the rays like this:

[Casting rays from the camera into the scene for each pixel](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28561/7777)
(2nd part of answer - F12 solution)

Then you build a [BVH tree](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.bvhtree.html) from your mesh:

```
import bpy
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree
depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
bvhtree = BVHTree.FromObject(bpy.context.active_object, depsgraph)
```

And you intersect this tree with the ray:

```
location, normal, index, dist = bvhtree.ray_cast(ray_origin, ray_direction)
```

You are interested in the `location`. The `index` and `normal` refer to the first polygon it intersected. If there's no hit, it returns `(None, None, None, None)` tuple.

It's wise to cache the bvhtree for performance reasons, its building is costly, but speeds up ray casting. The tree needs to be rebuild only when the object changes, this you get from the `object.is_updated` and `object.is_updated_data` [flags](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ID.html?highlight=is_updated_data#bpy.types.ID.is_updated).

Comment: So basicaly with def 2d_to_ray(context, point_px) I get ray_origin, ray_direction as ray_origin, ray_vector and then by running ray_cast from bvhtree I get in the location variable (X,Y and Z) of point of interest?

Comment: @DanButmalai Yes. The `2d_to_ray()` function is for getting viewport 2d pixels in 3d space when you are looking through the camera. If you only need to cast your rays from render pixels (this what I assume from your picture) and not viewport screen pixels you can skip that part as discussed in bottom of that answer.

Comment: Thanks for support provided, from all sources and discussions from other threads I managed to get a script that performs as required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know in which space `normal` is specified?

Comment: For the sake of future readers: I just verified with a plane that `normal` is in fact in the object's local space, which makes sense, since `location` is also in the object's local space.

Comment: @DanButmalai Can you please share the script which scans the whole FOV of the camera?

Comment: @AvivSham sorry I don't think still have it, but it was not that hard to write it.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone has problems implementing the ray casting mentioned in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28561/7777), here is a working example which casts rays from the camera into the scene. With this it should be easy to add the BVH method.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector, Quaternion
import numpy as np
import bmesh

# objects to consider
obj = bpy.data.objects['suzanne']
background = bpy.data.objects['plane']
targets = [background, obj]

# camera object which defines ray source
cam = bpy.data.objects['camera']

# save current view mode
mode = bpy.context.area.type

# set view mode to 3D to have all needed variables available
bpy.context.area.type = "VIEW_3D"

# get vectors which define view frustum of camera
frame = cam.data.view_frame(scene=bpy.context.scene)
topRight = frame[0]
bottomRight = frame[1]
bottomLeft = frame[2]
topLeft = frame[3]

# number of pixels in X/Y direction
resolutionX = int(bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x * (bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage / 100))
resolutionY = int(bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y * (bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage / 100))

# setup vectors to match pixels
xRange = np.linspace(topLeft[0], topRight[0], resolutionX)
yRange = np.linspace(topLeft[1], bottomLeft[1], resolutionY)

# array to store hit information
values = np.empty((xRange.size, yRange.size), dtype=object)

# indices for array mapping
indexX = 0
indexY = 0

# filling array with None
for x in xRange:
    for y in yRange:
        values[indexX,indexY] = None
        indexY += 1
    indexX += 1
    indexY = 0

# iterate over all targets
for target in targets:
    # calculate origin
    matrixWorld = target.matrix_world
    matrixWorldInverted = matrixWorld.inverted()
    origin = matrixWorldInverted @ cam.matrix_world.translation
            
    # reset indices
    indexX = 0
    indexY = 0
    
    # iterate over all X/Y coordinates
    for x in xRange:
        for y in yRange:
            # get current pixel vector from camera center to pixel
            pixelVector = Vector((x, y, topLeft[2]))
            
            # rotate that vector according to camera rotation
            pixelVector.rotate(cam.matrix_world.to_quaternion())

            # calculate direction vector
            destination = matrixWorldInverted @ (pixelVector + cam.matrix_world.translation) 
            direction = (destination - origin).normalized()
            
            # perform the actual ray casting
            hit, location, norm, face =  target.ray_cast(origin, direction)
            
            if hit:
                values[indexX,indexY] = (matrixWorld @ location)
            
            # update indices
            indexY += 1
                        
        indexX += 1
        indexY = 0
        
# create new mesh
# source: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/alternative-in-2-80-to-create-meshes-from-python-using-the-tessfaces-api/7445/3
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name='created mesh')
bm = bmesh.new()

# iterate over all possible hits
for index, location in np.ndenumerate(values):
    # no hit at this position
    if location is None:
        continue
    
    # add new vertex
    bm.verts.new((location[0], location[1], location[2]))  

# make the bmesh the object's mesh
bm.to_mesh(mesh)  
bm.free()  # always do this when finished
    
# We're done setting up the mesh values, update mesh object and 
# let Blender do some checks on it
mesh.update()
mesh.validate()

# Create Object whose Object Data is our new mesh
obj = bpy.data.objects.new('created object', mesh)

# Add *Object* to the scene, not the mesh
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.collection.objects.link(obj)

# Select the new object and make it active
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
obj.select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    
# reset view mode
bpy.context.area.type = mode

print("Done.")
```