# camera coverage simulation

Tags: modeling, python, camera, volumetrics

I am trying to create a camera coverage simulation where I will put multiple cameras inside a room with some objects to block the coverage of some cameras. Now, My job is to change the number and position of cameras such that the room is under full coverage of the cameras I have placed in that room setting.
My initial thoughts were, to fill all the empty space in the room with transparent small voxels and count all the voxels that are within the view of the cameras. How can I fill all the empty space of a room with transparent curve voxels and count the voxels that are in the coverage of the camera?

Comment: i would try a python script and raycast from the cameras. Then you know what camera will hit which voxels.

Comment: I searched over google but couldn't find any ray cast tutorial for blender. If you know any online references to the tutorial for the raycast, It would be really helpful.

Comment: maybe this helps you? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/115285/how-to-do-a-ray-cast-from-camera-originposition-to-object-in-scene-in-such-a-w

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.