# How can I tell if a mesh is visible and not occluded in a render with an orthographic camera using python

Tags: python, camera

I have an imported model with a complex set of parts, some of which are internal - i.e.: always occluded by other parts - think of an inside lining in a sofa.

Is it possible somehow to tell programmatically if some parts are visible in an orthographic view?

This is not about testing if they are in the camera's field of view - it is about checking if they are occluded by other parts.

I am thinking of color-coding them, rendering and checking if the color is visible, but I want to know if there's another way before going down this path.

Comment: I'd probably approach this with ray casting... This might help you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28557/problem-with-casting-rays-from-the-camera-into-the-scene-for-each-pixel/28561#28561